# Rest api header base versioning info to be kept in YAML file

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have achieved the header based rest Api versioning as shown in the below piece of code in my spring boot application in one of the controller but for that I have to annotate the same above the method name as shown below I have added the headers as X-API-VERSION=1

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}" ,  headers = "X-API-VERSION=1")
    public ResponseEntity<DomainDTO> retrieveDomainById(@PathVariable Integer id) throws ResourceNotFoundException {

        try {
            logger.info("inside domain controller");
            return ResponseEntity.ok(domainService.findById(id));
        } catch (ResourceNotFoundException e) {
            //log.error(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
```

but my query is that can I add the same at the rest controller level itself so that I do not have to it manually for each and every method and also please let me know can I keep the value of the headers it self in yaml file for that particular controller so that configuration if it needs to be changes so then in that case it will be read from a single configuration that is from YAML file itself.

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation you could use the `headers` parameter on the `@RequestMapping` annotation at the `@RestController` level: [RequestMapping documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#headers--)

> Supported at the type level as well as at the method level! **When used at the type level, all method-level mappings inherit this header restriction** (i.e. the type-level restriction gets checked before the handler method is even resolved).